# boto3 upload query result to s3 as csv file with few columns having a comma included in string

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, psycopg2

I have a cursor result with multiple rows with multiple columns in which name column has a value with comma in it as (sri, chil). when I do upload the result in to s3 the name column is getting separated into two columns . is there a way I can get this in to single column?

```
  file = io.StringIO()
  cur.execute(query)
  results = cur.fetchall()
  for row in results:
      s = ','.join(map(str,row))
      print(s)
      file.writelines("%s\n" % s)
  object = s3Client.Object(bucketName,f'{fileName}.csv' )
  result = object.put(Body=file.getvalue())
```

//results example : [('test1, Inc.', 324, 'test', 'eval', '3424, //None), ('test2, LLC', 423, '5343', 'prod', '232323', //datetime.date(2021, 3, 9))].
//test1, inc and test2, inc should be in single column but it is //getting added as two different columns in csv file

Comment: Could you add details on what results contain as well over here? At least a few records should help understand.

Comment: [('test1, Inc.', 324, 'test', 'eval', '3424, None), ('test2, LLC', 423, '5343', 'prod', '232323', datetime.date(2021, 3, 9))]. test1, inc and test2, inc should be in single column but it is getting added as two different columns in csv file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by modifying your code a bit to use csv module to do the csv file write as follows:

```
file = io.StringIO()
csvwriter = csv.writer(file, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,delimiter=',')
for row in results:
    csvwriter.writerow(row)

object = s3Client.Object(bucketName,f'{fileName}.csv' )
result = object.put(Body=file.getvalue())
```

Try writing the value to a file on your local filesystem and you can see how it pans out before trying the write to S3.